# Вызов метода объекта до его присвоения переменной

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, помогите разобраться почему такой код выдаст ошибку:

```
let user = {
  go: function () {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

(user).go()
```

А такой нет:

```
let user = {
  go: function () {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

user.go()
```

Как эти скобки влияют? Но если использовать скобки и поставить точку с запятой все будет работать:

```
let user = {
  go: function () {
    console.log(this)
  }
};

(user).go()
```

Недавно начал учить js после python и меня это немного путает. Заранее благодарю

Comment: А зачем собственно скобки вокруг `user`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson хороший вопрос. В целом это просто часть работы интерпретатора js. Он начинает воспринимать как часть предыдущего выражения инструкцию взятую в скобках. Просто не обращайте внимание

Comment: проблема в ASI - иногда подставляется точка с запятой иногда нет, поэтому ее лучше явно ставить всегда

Comment: @DenisLopatinЮ спасибо